# Excel 2010 Data Validation allow specific layout

Tags: excel, validation, wildcard

I want to apply data validation to reference numbers, to force the following layout (ideally uppercase only):

**XX_NNX-XX_NNN_NN-XXX**

X = Numbers

N = Letters

*Ex: 12_AB1-23_ABC_AB-123*

The following custom formula allows all of it except for numbers - is there any workaround for this?

I don't want to use * since it allows for more characters than I want.

`=COUNTIF(A1,"??_???-??_???_??-???")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose `AND` to add a condition to the function you have already written. e.g. following shall test the positions which shall be numeric.

`=AND(COUNTIF(A1,"??_???-??_???_??-???"),ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,6,1)&MID(A1,8,2)&RIGHT(A1,3))+0))`

**Notes:** This is fairly basic approach and may need some tweaks if you have cases involving usage of decimals etc.

**Edit:** You can try below approach for checking upper case text in specified positions.

`=AND(COUNTIF(A1,"??_???-??_???_??-???"),ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,6,1)&MID(A1,8,2)&RIGHT(A1,3))+0),INDEX(FREQUENCY(-CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),{-91,-65,0}),2)=7)`

**Edit2:** This turned out to be tougher than I had imagined. Following formula works in DV for cell `A1`.

`=AND(COUNTIF(A1,"??_???-??_???_??-???"),ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,6,1)&MID(A1,8,2)&RIGHT(A1,3))+0),MIN(FLOOR(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),65))=65,MAX(CEILING(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),90))=90)`

But due to some quirk, Excel won't let me simply paste it. So I wrote a small code for the same which applies DV to cell `A1` and surprisingly it accepts that same long formula through code. Make sure that you delete DV in the cell before you run this code.

```
With Range("A1")
    .Value = "12_AB1-23_ADC_AZ-123"
    .Validation.Add xlValidateCustom, , , "=AND(COUNTIF(A1,""??_???-??_???_??-???""),ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,6,1)&MID(A1,8,2)&RIGHT(A1,3))+0),MIN(FLOOR(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),65))=65,MAX(CEILING(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),90))=90)"
End With
```

Once in there, you can get it in any other cell by simply doing `copy >> Paste Special >> Validation`.

For clarity, I use Excel 2016.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

This solves the issue of numbers, but allows the Letters to be replaced with numbers - I tried messing around with the ISTEXT function, but to no avail so far.

Comment: @Snottus I have posted an edit. Please test and see if it helps your cause.

Comment: Was a bit quick in replying - the edited function isn't compatible with Data Validation (Unions, Intersections, and Ranges are not permitted), at least in Excel 2010

Comment: @Snottus you were correct! It turns out to be more difficult than I initially thought it to be. See edit 2. This is checked and tested in Excel 2016 and I'd hope that it works for you in Excel 2010!