# Excel Data Validation: Custom Formula Length limitation or bug?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**Background:** I came across an unusual behavior while dealing with Excel Data Validation Custom formula feature.

Here's the reference thread where it started for me.

[Excel 2010 Data Validation allow specific layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797748/excel-2010-data-validation-allow-specific-layout)

Basically, when I tried to input the following formula in Excel `Data Validation | Custom Formula` then Copy / Paste simply didn't work.

`=AND(COUNTIF(A1,"??_???-??_???_??-???"),ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,6,1)&MID(A1,8,2)&RIGHT(A1,3))+0),MIN(FLOOR(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),65))=65,MAX(CEILING(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),90))=90)`

It did accept Copy / Paste up to `65))=65` part but from there it wouldn't accept. I tried to type in some dummy text in addition to the pasted portion which Excel accepted. This lead me to think that the formula could be implemented via Excel VBA route. Following code works and adds DV to cell `A1`.

```
With Range("A1")
    .Value = "12_AB1-23_ADC_AZ-123"
    .Validation.Add xlValidateCustom, , , "=AND(COUNTIF(A1,""??_???-??_???_??-???""),ISNUMBER((LEFT(A1,2)&MID(A1,6,1)&MID(A1,8,2)&RIGHT(A1,3))+0),MIN(FLOOR(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),65))=65,MAX(CEILING(CODE(MID(MID(A1,4,2)&MID(A1,11,3)&MID(A1,15,2),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1)),90))=90)"
End With
```

> I am having Excel 2016. I'd suspect that original poster of the hyperlinked question might also face the same issue.

**Question:**

The limit surely seems to be above 180 (one search on SO says 210: [How to overcome the max length limit of a formula in Excel? a bug of excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604740/how-to-overcome-the-max-length-limit-of-a-formula-in-excel-a-bug-of-excel)) but through VBA one can implement DV beyond that limit. Why does the limit apply only to the formula box as Excel accepts the same long formula (271 characters long) through VBA macro?

I am thinking this is some kind of a bug in Excel.

Comment: Surely, this horrifying formula could be replaced with a range name with all kinds of advantages, not the least of which would be to avoid an argument whether there would be an underlying bug or just the limit to which Excel can be driven, if your observation is true, meaning there is no error in the formula. Whatever you write in that range could be selected using transparent and probably simple code - simple, at least, when compared to your admirable formula.

Comment: BTW, I seem to remember that the maximum length of characters in a validation list is 255 if entered in the `List` field where your formula is instead of a named range which I have recommended above.

Comment: @Variatus I agree but I do not want to venture out on the alternatives that can be implemented in this specific case and want to focus on the behavior that Excel shows.